# How to call user defined function within main function of Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

I have small application for validating our test reports. This will read the values from .rtf files and upload required values into a database. Now i have a small problem. I need to read some fields from database and load them onto a combo-box. I wrote a small function

```
    public void loadfromDB()
    {
       <Logic here
    }
```

I have Program.cs File from which i call Application.run(new frmMain).

Now i have to call my function at the start of my application. How to do this. I have just started learning c#.

Comment: call it in form constructor

Answer (score 0):

U need to double click on the form (from design view) so that it will
show up the Form1_Load event like:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 // You can call any of your functions
 loadfromDB();
}

public void loadfromDB()
{
// Logic here
}
```